# Checking if user already has the role, if they do, it will remove it

Tags: discord.js

So I tried to create a code that if a user already has the role, it will remove it, if they don't, then it will add the role. I worked out how to do it simply, but it removes it, and then adds it again. There are no errors inside the code. The command runs like "s!role  ".

````
var hasRole = false;
        SupervisorRoles.forEach(findrole =>{
            if(message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === findrole)) hasRole = true; //if user has role, sets bool to true
        })
    
        if(hasRole === true){
            let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first()) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) 
            if(!User) {
                message.delete()
                return;
            }
            if(args[1] === "Recruit") {

                if(User.roles.cache.get("846953430378610744")) {

                    message.delete()

                    User.roles.remove("846953430378610744")

                    const removedembed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .setDescription(`Removed role from ${User}`)
                .setColor("#feb90f")
                .setFooter(`Removed role at: ${moment(message.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY/H/ h:mm:ss a')}`)

                message.channel.send(removedembed1)

                    const removedembed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`${User.user.tag}`, User.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setDescription(`${User} roles has been updated by ${message.author}. \n \n  __**Updated Roles:**__ \n \n ❌ Recruit`)
                .setColor("#feb90f")
                .setFooter(`Removed role at: ${moment(message.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY/H/ h:mm:ss a')}`)

                client.channels.cache.get('851670920926199808').send(removedembed2)
                }
                
                User.roles.add("846953430378610744")

                message.delete()

                const addedembed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`${message.author.tag}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .setDescription(`Added role to ${User}`)
                .setColor("#feb90f")
                .setFooter(`Added role at: ${moment(message.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY/H/ h:mm:ss a')}`)

                message.channel.send(addedembed1)

                const addedembed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`${User.user.tag}`, User.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setDescription(`${User} roles has been updated by ${message.author}. \n \n  __**Updated Roles:**__ \n \n ✅ Recruit`)
                .setColor("#feb90f")
                .setFooter()
                .setFooter(`Added role at: ${moment(message.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YY/H/ h:mm:ss a')}`)

                client.channels.cache.get('851670920926199808').send(addedembed2)
            } else {
                message.delete()
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send("no perms")
        }

    }
    ```
````

Comment: That's not the way SO works. We don't go to a different site to get information about your question. All relevant information must be here in the question itself according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. Please [edit] your post to include that code here in the form of a [mre].

Comment: Edited, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 const roleName = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => (r.name === args[1].toString()) || (r.id === args[1].toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')));

    const alreadyHasRole = member._roles.includes(roleName.id);

     if(alreadyHasRole) {
    member.roles.remove(roleName).then(() => message.channel.send(removeEmbed))
    client.channels.cache.get(`${process.env.MSGLOG}`).send(logEmbed2);
    return;
    }
```

This will check if there is a role. You can always change the roleName variable.